# Move a mountpoint into a new lv without data loss RHEL6

Tags: rhel, mount, lvm

RHEL6. VMware VM.

I want to move /data and all the files it contains into a new lv in existing vg.

Currently:

/data is mapped directly onto sdc1 and is 100% full

```
/dev/sdc1             315G  299G   16M 100% /data
```

Fdisk shows sdc1 is 83 LINUX & it is not in pvs

```
 Disk /dev/sdc: 343.6 GB, 343597383680 bytes
 /dev/sdc1               1       41773   335541591   83  Linux
```

fstab

```
UUID=dc3fc363-2a6e-44c5-1234-ed59983762db /data     ext4    defaults        1 2
```

I have created a new lv of adequate size in a pre existing vg

```
/dev/mapper/vg_hostname01-lv_data
```

I then need to mount /data on this lv without losing any data.

What is the safest way of doing this?

I thought of creating a new mountpoint /datanew and rsync the data to that but then unsure how to nondestructive rename the new mountpoint back to the old name and if this step is really needed.

Comment: if you mean move LV from VG to VG consider working with lv snapshot export & import.

Comment: It is not currently on a VG, mounted direct to disk

Comment: possible duplicate - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/213906/move-data-from-regular-partition-to-lvm 
See if it helps.